# STM32 socket programming failed to connect with error code -3012

Tags: python, sockets, connection, stm32, mbed

I am doing socket programming using my STM32L4S5I board. I imported the program https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-sockets and did the below modification.

1. Modify mbed_app.json with my wifi SSID and password.
2. Add the below into "*" under "target_overrides" in mbed_app.json to have it support L4S5I board.

```
            "target.components_add": ["ism43362"],
            "ism43362.provide-default": true,
            "target.network-default-interface-type": "WIFI",
            "target.macros_add" : ["MBEDTLS_SHA1_C"]
```

3. Modify the host and port into the same as my computer(I used ipconfig to check it up)

And here is my python code which works as the server side running on my computer.

```
import socket 
import json
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
HOST = '192.168.0.155'     # IP address
PORT = 12345            # Port to listen on (use ports > 1023)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    print("Starting server at: ", (HOST, PORT))
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print("Connected at", addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(data)
```

After running both side, I get nothing except for "Starting server at:  ('192.168.0.155', 12345)" from the python side. And I get the below from console of the board.

```
Connecting to the network...
IP address: 192.168.0.52
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1

Resolve hostname 192.168.0.155
192.168.0.155 address is 192.168.0.155
Opening connection to remote port 12345
Error! _socket.connect() returned: -3012
```

It turned out that the socket was not connect successfully.
What does the error code "-3012" mean? Why did this happen? Does anyone know how to solve this or how to diagnose this?
I am using mbed os 6.16 version.

Comment: The source says: NSAPI_ERROR_DEVICE_ERROR        = -3012,     /*!< failure interfacing with the network processor */

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thank you for leave a comment. I know that it is Device Error, but I wonder why did this happen?